# Convert Integer Value to Hexadecimal in Ada

Tags: hex, ada

There is some kind of workaround to take advantage of the following and saving it?

```
Put_Line(MyNum, Base => 16);
```

which is converting for instance 255 to its proper value in hexadecimal FF, but just for display purposes. Can I do something similar, but to save the result?

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [version of Put that outputs to a string](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html#p18):

```
procedure Put(To   : out String;
              Item : in Num;
              Base : in Number_Base := Default_Base);
```

Answer (score 6):

*Can I do something similar, but to save the result?*

Yes, it's not "the simplest" way, but it's very general and flexible if you use Streams.

The wikibook has an example, though it's a little 'wordy' for what you intend: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Streams/Example

---

The simple "one-liner" is `Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put`.

Ada95's RM describes integer_text_IO in Annex A, 10.8.